# ListPlot, PlotMarker -> y value

Tags: plotting, graphics

at first sorry if this question is already answered.

I would like to display y value as plot marker in listplot

```
ll = {{33, 11, 2}, {3, 5, 4}, {6, 4, 8}}
Table[ListLinePlot[ll[[i, 1 ;; 3]], PlotLabel -> i, 
  PlotMarkers -> valueY], {i, 3}]
```

Gives me output like this:
[image: output from code]

and I'd like to have 33, 11, 2 instead of valueY.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean like this? (change your plot marker with) `PlotMarkers -> m[[1, i]]]`  there is was value associated with the symbol `valueY` you had. `m = {{33, 11, 2}, {3, 5, 4}, {6, 4, 8}}
Table[
 ListLinePlot[m[[i, All]],
  PlotLabel -> i,
  PlotMarkers -> m[[1, i]]],
 {i, 3}]`

Comment: I voted that this is a duplicate, although I must admit that your question is ambiguous, so my assessment was made mainly on the basis that doing it otherwise (as suggested in @Nasser's comment and the answer) does not make a lot of sense to me. It would be helpful if you could clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

Format will remain same as the plotting data, i.e. you can specify a separate marker for each point:

```
Table[ListLinePlot[ll[[i, 1 ;; 3]], PlotLabel -> i, 
  PlotMarkers -> ll[[i, 1 ;; 3]]], {i, 3}]
```