# Use y-values as PlotMarkers

Tags: plotting, legending

Is there an automatic function inserts y-values as PlotMarkers?

For instance, suppose I wish these four points in ListPlot to display as their values (2, 4, 6, and, 8 respectively):

```
ListPlot[#,PlotMarkers->#]&@{2,4,6,8}
```

This is what I get instead:

[image]

This is a duplicate of these two questions:

[ListPlot with plotmarkers determined by point](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7408/listplot-with-plotmarkers-determined-by-point)

[ListPlot, PlotMarker -> y value](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46624/listplot-plotmarker-y-value?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But since these were asked and answered in 2012 and 2014, respectively, and since MMA's functionality has expanded significantly since that time, I thought it was worth repeating the inquiry.

Comment: `ListPlot[List /@ Thread[{Range[Length[#]], #}], PlotMarkers -> #, PlotRange -> {{0, 4.1}, Automatic}] &@{2, 4, 6, 8}` If you don't want the different colors, include the option `PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][1]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
list = {2, 4, 6, 8};
ListPlot[Labeled[#, #, Center]& /@ list, PlotStyle -> None]
```

[image: labeled plot]

---

In the more general case in which coordinate pairs are specified, then the expression becomes:

```
dataXY = {{1, 3}, {2, 5}, {3, 7}, {4, 9}};
ListPlot[
  Labeled[#, #[[2]]] & /@ dataXY,
  PlotStyle -> None
]
```

[image: scatter plot using (x,y) coordinates and showing y value as label]

Comment: Nice.  And you can extend it to datasets with x and y values, as follows: `list = {{1.5, 2}, {3, 4}, {3.5, 6}, {7, 8}}; ListPlot[Labeled[#[[2]], #[[2]], Center] & /@ list, PlotStyle -> None]`.  However, this seems to break down when you have more than one x value with the same y, e.g., `list = {{1.5, 2}, {1.5, 3}, {3, 4}, {3.5, 6}, {7, 8}};`.  I know that wasn't explicitly in my OP; it seems in my attempt to give an MWE, I made it too minimal!  Would it be possible to extend this to cover such cases? [I can edit my OP to request that if you'd like.]

Comment: @theorist, use `Labeled[#, #[[2]], Center]` instead of `Labeled[#[[2]], #[[2]], Center]`

Comment: You can use `LabelingFunction -> Center` instead of mapping `Labeled` across the data.

Comment: @BrettChampion That converts the labels to machine-precision numbers shown as `2.` and `3.` (on MMA 12.3 on Win10-64), which may be ok, but it could be ugly.